# Data duplication with mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have used MongoDB aggregation and when I try to use sort and limit I get duplicate records.

As you can see below, I have 3 documents and from that `document1` and `document2` have the same title and `document3` has different video title.

I want to group documents by title and also sort the grouped documents by serial episode in desc order.

`document1` and `document2` will be in the same group and will get unique document2 and then now I want to sort this `document2` and `document3` with `video_view_count`.

```
/* document1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580afd565706467c1bbabd70"),
    "serial_episode" : "5",
    "video_view_count" : 50.0,
    "video_data" : [ 
        {
            "video_categories" : [ 
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title" : "Zwyci??zca",
            "language_id" : "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec4"
        }, 
        {
            "video_featured_text" : "",
            "video_categories" : [ 
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title" : "Zwyci??zca",
            "language_id" : "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec3"
        }
    ]
}

/* document2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580afd565706467c1bbabd71"),
    "serial_episode" : "6",
    "video_view_count" : 10.0,
    "video_data" : [ 
        {
            "video_categories" : [ 
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title" : "Zwyci??zca",
            "language_id" : "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec4"
        }, 
        {
            "video_featured_text" : "",
            "video_categories" : [ 
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title" : "Zwyci??zca",
            "language_id" : "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec3"
        }
    ]
}

/* document3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580afd565706467c1bbabd72"),
    "serial_episode" : "",
    "video_view_count" : 11.0,
    "video_data" : [ 
        {
            "video_categories" : [ 
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title" : "Zwyci??zca123",
            "language_id" : "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec4"
        }, 
        {
            "video_featured_text" : "",
            "video_categories" : [ 
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title" : "Zwyci??zca123",
            "language_id" : "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec3"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expexcted Output:**

I want a result with `document3` and then `document2` because docuemnt1-2 are group together to produce a uniqe `document2` and `docuemnt2` has the latest episode.
I need to compare `document2` and `document3` for video view count:

```
/* document3 */
{
    "_id": ObjectId("580afd565706467c1bbabd72"),
    "serial_episode": "",
    "video_view_count": 11,
    "video_data": [
        {
            "video_categories": [
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title": "Zwyci??zca123",
            "language_id": "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec4"
        },
        {
            "video_featured_text": "",
            "video_categories": [
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title": "Zwyci??zca123",
            "language_id": "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec3"
        }
    ]
},
/* document3 */
{
    "_id": ObjectId("580afd565706467c1bbabd71"),
    "serial_episode": "6",
    "video_view_count": 10,
    "video_data": [
        {
            "video_categories": [
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title": "Zwyci??zca",
            "language_id": "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec4"
        },
        {
            "video_featured_text": "",
            "video_categories": [
                "Sport"
            ],
            "video_title": "Zwyci??zca",
            "language_id": "578f1ec6e494f9400b21fec3"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Current Aggregate Operation:**

```
// Grouping that I have implemented 
var group = {   
    "$group": { 
        "_id":" $video_data.video_title",
        "video_rating" : { $first:" $video_rating" },
        "serial_episode" : { $first: "$serial_episode" },
        "video_view_count": { $first: "$video_view_count" },
    }
};

// Aggregate function to get that videos    
videos.aggregate([ 
    { $match: { "video_data.video_categories": query.category_name } },
    { $unwind: "$video_data" },
    { $sort: { video_view_count: -1 } },
    { $sort:{ serial_episode: -1 } },
    group,
    { $sort:{ video_view_count: -1 } },
    { $skip: skipData },
    { $limit: 10 }
], function(error, output){});
```

Comment: What are your sample documents and what's your expected output from the sample? Can you update your question with those two things?

Comment: Yes,sure, i have updated my question ,Please check now

Comment: What's your expected output from aggregating those sample docs?

Comment: i have mentioned in my question please check there you will understand.

Comment: I Have updated question with expected json output.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you unwinding it..? 
Remove unwind,it will multiply the document with the array length..

Comment: i have unwind because i have data in object array. like
{_id:1234655,
video_view_count:0
video_data:[
{
video_title:"Hello"
},
{
video_title:"HI"
}]

}

Comment: I think the problem is with your data.. In document 1 there is no "video_title" field use $exist

Comment: Can you tell what ouptut are you getting from your query

Comment: Please check now my question data.forgot to post video_title in question, sorry about that.and i am getting output with duplicate data because i have used limit for pagination.so if i remove limit then it's showing perfect data without duplication.